# password_hash and password_verify: using hardcoded hash always evaluated to false

Tags: php, password-hash

I have read the other posts to this topic but haven't found a solution to this one. Here is my code, reduced to the bare functionality:

```
<?php

$password = "YS7Wde5s";

$hashA = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo $hashA . "<br>";

// Copied from echo above
$hashB = "$2y$10$nltCAZhbMD2OILgq2ftWNOd6kJL8oidQ12CLEM5Gi1kIj5GxKtNhm";

if (password_verify($password, $hashA)) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
?>
```

The above code works well using `$hashA` to verify the password. BUT:

- The echo of `$hashA` returns a different hash whenever I reload the page.
- If I copy the echoed hash, hardcode it in `$hashB`, and use this instead of `$hashA`, I never get a true out of the `password_verify` call.

What am I missing? Is there an implicit type conversion I don't know about? Or am I completely wrong in how this should work?

Comment: Yes, thats why you should use this function because it is more secure that one that hashes the same string to the same hash always, like MD5 or SHA1

Comment: You get a different each time because Bcrypt appends a random value (commonly refered to as a "salt") to the password. This is done to prevent dictionary attacks on the database and force the attacker to brute-force the hash, which a computationaly expensive procedure.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I guessed that but wasn't sure about that.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. `BCRYPT` adds salt to prevent brute force. Its a good thing ;)

Comment: you mention that `password_verify()` on `$hashB` never returns `true`, if you are using the same password, it should work, there may be something wrong with the way you are verifying it

Comment: @Sammitch that's already what OP is doing

Comment: Thats why `password_verify()` is provided. It will look at the HASH and use the same salt and Cost count as was used in the original HASH. See those are stored in the HASH and `password_verify()` knows how to get the right bits from the original hash

Comment: The problem is the double quotes around the `$hashB` value; with double-quoted strings, variable interpolation is attempted (looking for a variable called  `$nltCAZhbMD2OILgq2ftWNOd6kJL8oidQ12CLEM5Gi1kIj5GxKtNhm`).  If you turn on displaying `E_NOTICE` messages, you'll see *"Notice: Undefined variable: nltCAZhbMD2OILgq2ftWNOd6kJL8oidQ12CLEM5Gi1kIj5GxKtNhm"*. The value of `$hashB` is actually only `"$2y$10"`.

Comment: @WilliamPerron What you are saying is that using $hashB using the echoed hash in the above code SHOULD return true. Right?

Comment: @salathe This. The problem has nothing to do with the password APIs; it's a syntax issue.

Comment: @salathe GENIUS!

Comment: @SirTobi if `$hashB` was generated using the same password as `$hashA`, then using `password_verify()` with that password and `$hashB` should work

Comment: @salathe great catch, I wouldn't have thought of that, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 6):

The double quotes around $hashB are causing everything within the hash value following the $, to be interpreted as a variable. (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Use single quotes instead.

The following note on the php manual explains it better than I:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php#115120

Comment: Noted, but the link provided explains it better than I can.

Comment: I wouldn't even consider it an issue at all, let alone a "well known issue". This is just how PHP works.

Comment: @Mike "Issue" as in "something to keep in mind"

Comment: @WilliamPerron Maybe "snag" would be a better way to put it. "Issue" to me sounds like something that should be fixed.

Comment: *"I suspect"* and *"Try"* IMHO are signs of being unsure and more fit to be comments. This needs to be modified to state that that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be more direct in any future contributions.

Comment: why not fix the answer now?